# Настроить кол-во выводимых постов в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Вывожу посты определённой рубрики на главную. В таком виде выводятся все посты рубрики, а как сделать, чтобы выводилось несколько последних?

```php
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : query_posts('cat=8'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

//контент

<?php the_content();
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();                
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте параметр `posts_per_page` для этого:

```
query_posts( [
    'cat'            => 8,
    'posts_per_page' => 3
] );
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while (have_posts()) : 
        the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```